# JS UNDO DOM modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible to undo last DOM modification?

I've tried to remember state after any change by

```
undoArray = [ $("#container").clone() ];

//some situation when dom changed and remember state
undoArray.push( $('#container').clone() );
```

And then, if needed, to restore `#container` content from this array, but it was loosing all events attached directly to elements.

Comment: If the only problem is event handling of dynamically generated elements, event delegation is the answer.

Comment: No, there is no built-in way to undo a modification. Yes, if you build a system which lets you "undo" a modification, you'll have to account for a lot of details, like events.

Comment: See the `withDataAndEvents` parameter for [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/). That may work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `true` to `.clone()` to keep events and data.

```
undoArray = [ $("#container").clone(true) ];
```

Docs for [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Just remember to clean the data if you're going to destroy an item in the Array without putting it in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist the events then pass `true` for **[clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)**  `withDataAndEvents`

```
  $("#container").clone(true)
```

or attach using **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to the `document`

```
  $(document).on('eventName','targetSelector', eventHandler);
```